# YUM dependency issue

Tags: linux, postfix

I've installed Percona Xtradb server but in order to install it I had to remove "mysql-libs.x86_64" package and now I'm not able to install any package that depends on it (postfix, Nagios mysql plugin etc).

```
# yum install postfix
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.mhd.uk.as44574.net
 * epel: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirror.mhd.uk.as44574.net
 * updates: mirror.mhd.uk.as44574.net
77 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.6.6-2.2.el6_1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package Percona-Server-shared-51.x86_64 0:5.1.62-rel13.3.435.rhel6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: 1:Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-5.5.23-23.5.333.rhel6.x86_64 conflicts Percona-Server-shared-51
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared conflicts with Percona-Server-shared-51
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've checked and "Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared" package provide newer libraries .18 but postfix requires .16. What' s the best solution for this?

```
# rpm -ql Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.0.0
```

Regards

Comment: Have you tried downloading the RPMS (with `yum --downloadonly`) and then forcing an install of postfix with `rpm -i --nodeps`? Though this won't guarantee that postfix will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the shared-compat package. That'll provide the libmysql your distro expects. Works the same if you're running the latest RPMs from Mysql as well.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever packaged these `Percona-*` packages screwed up. The `*.so` files should be in separate `-devel` packages, which will make them not conflict, which means that the corresponding `Conflicts` tag can be removed from the spec files.